# How can I free a generic TList<T>?

Tags: delphi

How can I free a generic `TList<T>`?

I know I can use a `TObjectList` with `AOwnsObjects = True` while creating it.

I am curious, how can I rewrite the following method in a generic fashion so it can free `T` when `T` is an unmanaged reference, either a pointer or a class?

```pascal
procedure FreeList(const List: TList);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if (List = nil) then
    Exit;
  for i := Pred(List.Count) downto 0 do
    if Assigned(List[i]) then
      TObject(List[i]).Free;
  List.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't free the list, just clears it.

Comment: Why do you need to handle arbitrary element types? Use `TObjectList<T>` and there is nothing more to do.

Comment: Related: see [Testing the type of a generic in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042997/) and [Undocumented intrinsic routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417218/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `T` Generic parameter to your procedure (which must then be made into a class method in order to use Generics with it), and use RTTI to check if `T` is a class type before calling `Free()` on your list elements.

For example:

```pascal
type
  ListUtils = class
  public
    class procedure ClearList<T>(const List: TList<T>);
  end;

class procedure ListUtils.ClearList<T>(const List: TList<T>);
type
  PObject = ^TObject;
var
  i: Integer;
  Value: T;
begin
  if (List = nil) then
    Exit;
  if GetTypeKind(T) = tkClass then
  // for older compilers that do not have GetTypeKind():
  // if PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T))^.Kind = tkClass then
  begin
    for i := Pred(List.Count) downto 0 do
    begin
      Value := List[i];
      PObject(@Value)^.Free;
    end;
  end;
  List.Clear;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.Rtti;

type
  ListUtils = class
  public
    class procedure ClearList<T>(const List: TList<T>);
  end;

class procedure ListUtils.ClearList<T>(const List: TList<T>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if (List = nil) then
    Exit;
  if GetTypeKind(T) = tkClass then
  // for older compilers that do not have GetTypeKind():
  // if PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T))^.Kind = tkClass then
  begin
    for i := Pred(List.Count) downto 0 do
      TValue.From<T>(List[i]).AsObject.Free;
  end;
  List.Clear;
end;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```pascal
var
  IntList: TList<Integer>;
  ObjList: TList<TSomeClass>;
begin
  IntList := TList<Integer>.Create;
  ...
  // does not call TObject.Free on list elements
  ListUtils.ClearList<Integer>(IntList);
  IntList.Free;

  ObjList := TList<TSomeClass>.Create;
  ...
  // calls TObject.Free on list elements
  ListUtils.ClearList<TSomeClass>(ObjList);
  ObjList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @Remy: as stated, my question was generated by simple curiosity and your answer satisfied it.

Comment: Does not compile under Berlin: two errors. The fisrst is E2530 Type parameters not allowed on global procedure or funcion FreeList<T>, the second is E2003 Udeclared identifier 'T' at the method signature const List: TList<T>

Comment: @FabioVitale oh yeah, I keep forgetting about the issue that Generics don't work on standalone procedures (I really hate that restriction). So, just make the procedure be a `class` method instead. I updated my answer to show that

Comment: Hi @Remy, still I get an error E2089 Invalid Typecast at the line TObject(List[i]).Free;

Comment: Thank you so much @Remy: it works like a charm and now I have a better grasp on the whole thing!

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic version, `TObjectList<T>`.